# ClickOnce open file security warning in certified application

Tags: wpf, installation, certificate, clickonce

My ClickOnce WPF 4.0 application can be downloaded and installed locally. The prerequisite installer and the executable file of the application itself are signed by Comodo. There is **no** "Unknown publisher" prompt. This works great so far.

But users still get a "Open File - Security Warning" from Windows telling them the file is downloaded from the internet (mentioning me as publisher). Shouldn't this be already addressed with the certification? It really diminishes trust in my application since its shown on every start as long as the user doesn't uncheck the CheckBox "Always ask before opening this file".

Comment: Do you get the prompt on every version of windows, or is it just Windows 8?

Comment: @RobinDotNet Yes, that seems to be right. I can't reproduce it with Windows Vista or 7.

Comment: I've just started having this exact same issue. Only happens on Windows 8, not on any other OS. I have yet to figure out why. Even if you uncheck the always ask checkbox, it comes back at the next update.

Comment: Did anyone resolve this issue. I've just jumped through the hoops to get the exe signed as part of the build but this is still coming up! :( I wouldn't mind so much but as @Ricky says when the app is updated the path changes and the prompt will just re-appear even if you get the user to un-check the "always ask" checkbox!

Comment: I'm now running Windows 8.1 with the "update", and I no longer see this issue. I was also having problems getting clickonce applications to even run when not executed by the installer. I have a feeling there was a bug in Windows 8 which was causing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prompt did disappear after some time so I thought it to be a glitch of Windows 8 like Ricky assumed. But when I had to update my certificate I had the same problem again, this time with Windows 8.1. It took some days but finally it doesn't occur any more.

I assume the reputation of the application has increased to a level where it no longer needs to show the prompt.

Comment: The installer never has a problem. I can force an update by setting Minimum Required Version and since the package manifest is signed it deploys right away. My problem is that I still get the "always ask before opening this file" prompt on Windows 10 every time I update the app, even though the app is signed with the same certificate as the manifest and it's SHA256 and timestamped and everything.